# css3 slide page transitions

Tags: html, css

I would like to do the page transition in the mobile app by using html5 and css3, how can i do that? I don't want to use jQuery, because it is very heavy. can anyone can suggest another framework to do page transition in mobile device?

Answer (score -1):

How about

1. MooTools? [Link here](http://mootools.net)
2. SenchaTouch(libraries specifically for Mobile devices) [link here](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)

Comment: Sencha touch is very heavy too. MooTools page transition do not have page transition between 2 html page.

Comment: How do you classified a library as heavy or not heavy?